# Running Heroku app not showing the changes in the uploaded files

Tags: node.js, heroku, push, heroku-cli, nodejs-server

I push updates to Heroku

```
git push Heruko master
```

then go and run my app from the Heroku page and the changes are not showing in the running app.

If **I run bash** and look at the files on Heroku, the changes are in the files.
It shows "Everything is up-to-date" message and no code reflects.

I've tried restarting the app and the changes are still not reflected in the running app.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to build your front and copy that folder to the public folder on the backend... it's happen to me ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. check the git log to check the date and the name of the commit you are uploading.
2. if the commit is right, try deleting the existing app on heroku and upload again
3. Check in your package.json, the start script is pointing to your server.js file